# Domain Forwarding | A Magento Store

Tags: domain

I have installed Magento inside a folder called magento. The URL of the site currently looks like this:
`http://gios.azamdevelopment.co.uk/magento/`
We want our domain forwarded to the above URL and moreover, any links relative should work as well. 
e.g. `http://gios.azamdevelopment.co.uk/magento/customer/account/login/`
should ideally
be `www.giosconcept.com/customer/account/login` 
and so forth.

Thanks very much.

Comment: this is better suited to our sister site, Server Fault.  it will be migrated there shortly; please don't crosspost.  you will need to register an account on SF and associate your accounts together to regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this on the domain level, as domains don't handle protocol-specific information.

One way you can accomplish this:
If you have apache running on www.giosconcept.com, add `Redirect / http://gios.azamdevelopment.co.uk/magento/` to the configuration which is responsible for serving the www.giosconcept.com domain. This is simplest, but won't preserve the URL in the user's address bar.

If both domains are hosted on the same server, you can probably use apache's `Alias` directive to make the website behave exactly as you wish, including showing the proper URL in the user's address bar. In fact, if this is the case, you should be able to set the same directory to the root of the www.giosconcept.com domain (using the `Directory` directive)

Comment: Hi Darth thanks for your reply.

this is what I did:

I created a new folder called gioslive and copied the magento installation here.

Then forwarded the domain to this directory.
However, now if you surf http://www.giosconcept.com/ it throws a PHP error. I dont know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @WaZ Many php packages need to know both the path to the installation directory and the url to reach the root of the package. Double check that these are accurate after moving the files. Otherwise I can't help any more without more detailed information on the error.